# Weird behavior on cqlsh while creating table in cassandra from putty

Tags: cassandra, putty, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to create one table in `Cassandra` using `cqlsh` having the following syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE usertracking (
          cwc text,
          cur_visit_id text,
          cur_visit_datetime timestamp,
          cur_visit_last_ts bigint,
          prev_visit_datetime timestamp,
          prev_visit_last_ts bigint,
          tot_page_view bigint,
          tot_time_spent bigint,
          tot_visit_count bigint,
          PRIMARY KEY (cwc)
        );
```

But for some reason when i paste the syntax on `cqlsh` it automatically get converted into the following syntax. Can anyone please explain this behavior. I am using putty to connect to my cassandra cluster. Which is running on ubuntu.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your copy pasting from an editor with newline character at the end of every line.

Write the query in a single line and then copy and paste it to putty.

Also if you are on *nix machine use the terminal to ssh rather that using putty. It will have better text editing features than putty

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce this symptom.  My guess is you're making a cut and paste error.  Somehow you are pasting text that has the '...' continuation characters in it already.  Those are printed by cqlsh during manual entry, but they should not be input by the user.